# HaxeFlixel: make object disappear in certain area

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to make a game where you can capture floating lights that moves randomly in the air. In the game there is going to be 3 different boxes where you can put the floating lights, so there is also going to be 3 different lights.

The lights works properly and I am able to drag them around like I want.

My issue is how to catch them and re-spawn them. I want to use the `kill()` method that you find in the `flixel.FlxNapeSprite`.

When you catch them, you should move them to the correct box, and when they come inside the box, they should get killed, you get points, and a new random light re spawn.

[Link to image](http://prntscr.com/6wg723) of the game so far

How do I kill the light-object inside a certain area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the boxes are `FlxNapeSprite`s as well? Typically you would set up a collision callback here, which is called whenever the hitboxes of two nape bodies overlap (the light and the box in this case). You can display the nape bodies with `napeDebugEnabled = true` or by pressing the "N" button in the top right of flixel's debugger overlay.

Here's a simple example of how to set up a simple collision callback using Flixel + Nape:

```
package;

import flixel.addons.nape.FlxNapeSprite;
import flixel.addons.nape.FlxNapeState;
import flixel.util.FlxColor;
import nape.callbacks.CbEvent;
import nape.callbacks.CbType;
import nape.callbacks.InteractionCallback;
import nape.callbacks.InteractionListener;
import nape.callbacks.InteractionType;
import nape.phys.BodyType;
using flixel.util.FlxSpriteUtil;

class PlayState extends FlxNapeState
{
    override public function create()
    {
        super.create();
        bgColor = FlxColor.BLACK;
        napeDebugEnabled = true;

        var light = new Light(10, 10);
        var box = new Box(10, 100);

        add(light);
        add(box);

        light.body.velocity.y = 200;

        FlxNapeState.space.listeners.add(new InteractionListener(
            CbEvent.BEGIN, 
            InteractionType.COLLISION, 
            Light.CB_TYPE,
            Box.CB_TYPE,
            collideLightBox));
    }

    function collideLightBox(callback:InteractionCallback)
    {
        var light:Light = cast callback.int1.castBody.userData.sprite;
        light.kill();
    }
}

class Light extends FlxNapeSprite
{
    public static var CB_TYPE(default, null) = new CbType();

    public function new(x:Float, y:Float)
    {
        super(x, y);
        makeGraphic(10, 10, FlxColor.TRANSPARENT);
        var radius = 5;
        drawCircle(5, 5, radius, FlxColor.WHITE);
        createCircularBody(radius);
        body.cbTypes.add(CB_TYPE);
        // we need this to get the Light instance in the callback later
        body.userData.sprite = this;
    }
}

class Box extends FlxNapeSprite
{
    public static var CB_TYPE(default, null) = new CbType();

    public function new(x:Float, y:Float)
    {
        super(x, y);
        makeGraphic(100, 50, FlxColor.GREEN);
        createRectangularBody(width, height);
        body.cbTypes.add(CB_TYPE);
        body.type = BodyType.STATIC;
    }
}
```

Be sure to check out the official [FlxNape](http://haxeflixel.com/demos/FlxNape/) demo. The [Nape website](http://napephys.com/help.html) also has some very helpful examples + docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really helpful. I have seen the demos and that was where me and my friend got our inspiration making this game.